# find 2d gaussian in image in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

The left image is my result image after some processing. the right image is after running peak detection on the result image

How do I filter the image to only get the middle peak, which approximates to a 2d gaussian or circle, compared to the line on the right or peaks on the left that are quite spread out.

I need the filter to generalize across different peak sizes and imperfect gaussian/circle to some degree and be very fast

I tried eroding with different shapes (eg: circle, vertical/horizontal line) but that only created circles instead of removing non-circles

I thought about running a 2D gaussian as a filter with small positive numbers in the middle and large negative numbers on the edges but that would be sensitive to the size of the filter

Maybe i could use the detected peaks as starting points and "descend" the peak checking an increasing radius around it for almost uniform decrease until it reaches a certain threshold? But i fear manually coding that would be very slow

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using hough circles on your binary image?

Comment: no, without doing edge detection, hough would return alot of false positives without filtering out non circles. with edge detection, it wont generalize well because the edges are gradual and not perfectly circular

Comment: Read up in the structure tensor. Then, think about what it looks like in the middle of a dot vs on a line. Next, read up on Frangi’s vesselness measure and Shi-Tomasi corner detector. They both use the structure tensor. Either one will get you to your solution.